# Non-trivial integrals of motion of a double pendulum?

Tags: classical-mechanics, ergodic-theory, chaos-theory

I was always assuming that a [double pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum) does not have any non-trivial integrals of motion besides the Hamiltonian, but after asking [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4282751/double-pendulum-is-non-ergodic?noredirect=1#comment8914452_4282751) I tried to simulate the motion of the pendulum, and I was surprised.

The motion of a double pendulum is described by [4 differential equation](https://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/DoublePendulum.html), and if there were no non-trivial integrals of motion, one would expect the trajectory to cover a 3D manifold (corresponding to constant energy) in the 4D phase space. What I discovered, was that the motion is constrained to a 2D surface (see the picture, which shows the projection of the trajectory of $(\theta_1, \theta_2, \dot{\theta_1}, \dot{\theta_2})$ with initial position $(1,0,0,0)$ onto a 3D space and then onto the 2D screen). It may be not very easy to see from this picture, but I am positive it is a 2D manifold (after rotating it for a while). So, is there an extra integral of motion or is there not one? I saw some people mentioning [local integrals in a physics post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142238/non-integrability-of-the-2d-double-pendulum), but I am not sure what to make of it with respect to this result. Could someone educate me why the motion is constrained to a 2D manifold, when one naively would expect it to be constrained to a 3D manifold? [image]